# Can anyone help me to identify this plant?

Tags: identification

I have this mysterious plant in my back garden. Seems like it might be a tree, can anyone have any idea what it might be?
If it help, I live in eastern part of UK. Plant was always in a pot outside, and is around 2 years old.
I'm happy with answers  which gives me rough ideas what is that.

[image][image]
**Edit**
As requested I added close up on leaves.
[image]

Comment: The leaves made me think of some kind of mulberry, right away. I'm in the USA, and I see that you are in the UK. But, the leaves seem to be very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crab apple? I think the dust on the stems give it away- and that apple look of the leaves- hardy, outside, uk, yeah I think it is a form of the apple family?
hope it helps.

Comment: I already asked this in few gardening centres, and crab apple is most common answer.